# phpMyAdmin does not run SQL and shows "Loading" message

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

I installed Ubuntu 12.04 with its LAMP stack:

- PHP 5.3.10
- MySQL 5.5.24
- Apache 2.2.22
- phpMyAdmin 3.4.10.1deb1.

phpMyAdmin is working except when I run SQL query sometimes it runs OK but in most cases phpMyAdmin shows “Loading” message on the yellow background and then stops running the query like nothing happened without giving any error message.

I tried to run incorrect SQL code and phpMyAdmin does not show any errors, just shows “Loading” message.

I run those SQL queries via older phpMyAdmin on older versions of LAMP without problems.

Comment: I would reinstall if I were you :D

Answer (score 2):

I have experienced this too in a WAMP stack-- it appears to happen when the result of the query would be an empty result. You can verify this by running the same query from the mysql CLI, or alter the query to ensure that some records match the search.

I assume this may be a bug in phpmyadmin.